# Scroll site block by block

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, block

I`ve seen some one-page sites, where you scroll block by block, so you don't have a unlimited scrolling.

You move block by block.

Is there any script or something which provides this feature?

Answer (score 0):

I've never used this myself so I can't help you with the code side of things, but you could be looking for Parallax Scrolling?

Here are some examples: http://www.awwwards.com/20-best-websites-with-parallax-scrolling-of-2013.html